# mod_rewrite does not work

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, web

I have the following page name

```
http://example.co.uk/vehicle.php?size=large
```

and I have written the following rewrite rule so the domain should look as follows

```
http://example.co.uk/size/large
```

Here is the rule

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^size/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ vehicle.php?size=$1
```

I have two problems:

- The first is its not working. In fact its not working at all.
- The second is if it does work then it will remove the page name which I don't want. I'm struggling to see my mistake in the first place to fix it but I want the domain to look as follows:

```
http://example.co.uk/vehicle/size/large
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to redirect from `/vehicle.php` URLs to `/vehicle/` URLs, then try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*?)=(.*?)$
RewriteRule ^vehicle\.php /vehicle/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

As for displaying contents of nonclean URLs (like `/example.php?foo=bar`) at clean URLs (like `/example/foo/bar`), there is a cyclic-redirection issue when trying to use both internal (from a to b) and external (from b to a) redirections at the same time.

If you've decided to switch to clean URLs, then I would recommend you to use `/index.php` as the only handler for *all* requests, and use mod_rewrite *solely* to redirect from old URLs to clean ones. Moreover, I usually perform most of operations with PHP (by parsing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` via PHP), and use mod_rewrite solely to map all requests to `index.php` file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L,QSA]
```

That's most flexible, straightforward, and portable solution.

Comment: thanks for the response but that did not work at all.  The url is just displaying as http://example.co.uk/vehicle.php?size=large

Comment: Please provide entire ruleset. Do you still have `RewriteEngine On` (it is needed for mod_rewrite to work)? What URL are you requesting? The rule is intended to show contents of `/vehicle.php?size=large` when `/vehicle/size/large` is requested.

Comment: This is the first re write rule I have written for this site. the entire rule is  RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/vehicle/(.*?)/(.*?)/$ /vehicle.php?$1=$2

Comment: The current url is /vehicle.php?size=large but I want it to show  /vehicle/size/large to anyone that hits the page as its more seo friendly

Comment: So you want to _redirect_ to `/vehicle/size/large` when `/vehicle.php?size=large` is requested? Then swap first and seconds parts patterns and add ` [R=permanent]` at the end of the rule. I've updated the answer.

Comment: you mean like this?  RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/vehicle.php?$1=$2(.*?)/(.*?)/$ /vehicle/ [R=permanent]

Comment: I must be missing something coz its still not working.  Here is the real web address so you can seee for yourself http://www.van-smart.co.uk/vehicle.php?size=small Marat thank you for your time

Comment: Updated the answer. Now tested myself. ;-)

Comment: it works!!!! thank you but.  if you load my page youll see it has made the page error   I get a 404 not found  http://www.van-smart.co.uk/vehicle/size/small

Comment: Added corresponding note to the answer.